# Testing subscription renewals on Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment, webhooks, subscriptions

I am using Stripe to test how my code would react to recurring subscription renewal payment attempts for a product we are working on (need to test success, failure ...etc.). And it seems that most answers on StackOverflow suggest creating a subscription with a recurring payment of 1 day (which is the minimum recurring payment available at Stripe), and waiting until next day to see how my code would react to the webhook notifications. (By the way, I could not find much documentation on Stripe to suggest testing methodologies for recurring payment).

I do not agree much with this approach, because it stretches the testing of my code to more than a week, maybe even two, but in normal conditions I might finish that testing within a couple of hours.

I think one of the following two approaches would be sufficient to do my coding/testing.

1. Find a way to make recurring subscription interval happen on shorter custom periods, such as every 15 minutes, or every 10 minutes.
2. A better solution is to make recurring subscriptions trigger on demand. That is, I create a subscription, and then I would update the date for the next renewal manually to a custom value, such as "1 minute in the future" or "30 seconds in the future" which would trigger the payment attempt.

Is there a way of doing any of those two options in Stripe? If neither is a viable option, how do I test recurring payments efficiently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Our solution was to reset the billing cycle of the subscription.

- open the subscription in Stripe
- click "Actions" in the upper right
- select "Update Subscription"
- be sure to switch off "Prorate changes"
- scroll down and open "Advanced Options"
- check "Reset billing cycle"
- and finally... Update Subscription

This will trigger a new subscription payment and all the associated webhooks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple method

Definitely @Marc found the great option for arbitrarily subscription renewal. The same action he described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68191847/14648074) can be done programmatically or with the Stripe CLI:

```
stripe subscriptions update sub_id \
  --proration-behavior=none \
  --billing-cycle-anchor=now
```

This command generates the following sequence of events:

```
charge.succeeded
invoice.finalized
invoice.created
invoice.paid
invoice.payment_succeeded
customer.subscription.updated
payment_intent.succeeded
payment_intent.created
```

#### Advanced method

The use of [test clock](https://stripe.com/docs/api/test_clocks) gives more opportunities to verify your system's behavior. It is possible to attach test clock not only to the `Subscription` object.

Answer (score 0):

So I would start with their [testing documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test) It walks you through the process.

it seems that you can trigger events on the fly with CLI commands.

Also look at the [Webhook Monitor](https://github.com/stripe-archive/stripe-webhook-monitor)